# the best way to get only one object in jquery

Tags: jquery, performance

I'm building a plugin in jquery. As they say in the docs, this references to a jquery object. so you can do a `.each()` and then return as many objects as you get in the plugin constructor.
However, this plugin returns a scalar value, so I only can act on the first object.

If I want to get the first element from the jquery possible array of objects, what do you think would be the best approach ?

```
$.fn.totalWidth = function(element){
    $this = $(this.get(0)); //option 1
    //OR
    $this = this.first(); //option 2
});
```

I'll appreciate your points of view.

Comment: Just a guess here... but get(0) would seem to assume that an item exists in the array.  If not, it would return an index out of bounds.  .First could be coded to check, and return smoothly, so that'd be my preference.

Comment: @Scottie - you can't really chain the plugin without first having an element, so that much is implied.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the plugins scope,

```
this.first()
```

or

```
this.eq(0)
```

would be the best way to get the first element, as `this` references the jQuery object in a plugin, and does'nt have to be wrapped again. Using `.get()` to get the native element just to rewrap it again seems uneccessary.

Answer (score 1):

$this = $(this.get(0)); will retrieve the dom element matched the query where as first() will get you the jquery object.

If you would like to do jquery operations on resulting object then go for option 2
If you want pure javascript dom object go for option 1.